# How to hide out of stock products in Related Products via custom query in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to hide out of stock items from the Related Products section of WooCommerce. I don't want to edit theme files, so want to do this via functions.php.

I have followed [this blog post](https://iconicwp.com/blog/hide-stock-products-related-products-woocommerce/), which a lot of other sites have as the solution to this problem, but it does not work properly (it simply hides out of stock products, so if there are 6 related products, and 2 are out of stock, sometimes only 2 or 3 related products will be shown on the page.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23554993/output-posts-relating-to-the-tags) that gives a great over view of the related_proucts filters available, but it doesn't seem to want to work when I apply a meta_query to filter in stock products only.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', function( $args )
{
    unset( $args['meta_query'] );
    $args['meta_query'] = array(
        'key' => '_stock_status',
        'value' => 'outofstock',
        'compare' => '='
    );
    return $args;
});
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. None of the blog posts out there are accurate it seems.

Put this in your functions.php file. You can change the posts per page number to see if its working straight away or not.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_output_related_products_args', function( $args )
{
    $args = wp_parse_args( array(
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'meta_query' => array (
           'key' => '_stock_status',
           'value' => 'instock'
    )
    ), $args );
    return $args;
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work with backorder products. They are shown despite the _stock_status = instock

Comment: @retroriff That wasn't the question given or the solution offered